# Angular: Slice pipe not giving expected result

Tags: angular, pipe, slice

I'm using Angular 6 with angular instantsearch.
Inside an overview of my results I want to print a "description"-property of my results, but just the first 500 letters.
For that purpose I want to use the built-in slice pipe.

I think I use it as described in the official Angular API but the description is still shown as the full text, not sliced at all.
Do you have any ideas?

The code looks like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="5px">
            <ais-highlight attribute="description" [hit]="hit">
              <p>{{ hit.description | slice:0:100 }}</p>
            </ais-highlight>
            <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" (click)="projectDetail(hit.id)">Projekt anzeigen</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to work when I tried it in StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgsen4?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: At some other point on my page it is working as well...
Might there be problems with angular instantsearch or because I used an *ngFor in the surrounding div?

Comment: Are you able to create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the used algolia data is for work purpose, therefore I'm not allowed to share it.
But actually just found out that removing the ais-highlight tags solves the issue. 
Any idea how to use the ais-highlight combined with slice?